# symbolic x coords not aligning correctly, missing data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I compile this code:

```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title= Website FC Club-Brugge,
    width  = 0.9*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    %minor y tick style = transparent,
    ybar,
    bar width=35pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=25,
    xlabel = {Dag van de week},
    ylabel = {Aantal bezoekers},
    symbolic x coords={ma,di,woe,don,vrij,zat,zon},
    minor ytick={0,1,...,25},
    xtick = data,
    %enlarge x limits=0.50,
    scaled y ticks = false,
]
    \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
        coordinates {(ma,35) (di,13) (woe,16) (don,13) (vrij,23) (zat,18) (zon,19)};

   % \legend{Karel,Fien,Peter,Wim}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output is not correct for the labels of the x-axe (not on the same height) and the data for "ma" is not displaying. I can not find what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Update, changing the data (ma,35) to (ma,24) makes ma displaying ok. But still not in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ma` bar is missing because its value (`35`) lies outside the visible range of your axis (`0` to `25`). Setting `ymax=35` fixes this.

To correct the alignment of the labels, set `xticklabel style={text height=1.5ex}`.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it stays strange that it doesn't do this automatically correct.

Comment: @Arne: What do you mean? The axis limits or the alignment of the labels?

Comment: The alignment of the labels. (the (ma,35) was a stupid error of me :-( )